# Codeigniter update function doesn't work corectly

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem with the update function. This code is updating all rows in database and i want to update only the row with the login username.The "password" is one that i logged in and i want to replace with password3. The problem is that password replace all rows(passwords) in my database.

```
function edit_member()
{
    $new_member_update_data = array(
                'password' => md5($this->input->post('password3'))
                );
    $this->db->where('password',$this->input->post('password'));
    $update = $this->db->update('memberships',$new_member_update_data);
    return $update; 
}
```

Comment: you need a unique id of the logged in user to, so that with that id you can monitor, update that user with that unique id.

Comment: you mean to replace password in my code with id $this->db->where('password',$this->input->post('password'));

Comment: where(id, ????); can you give me a idea?

Comment: yes, please show your `memberships` table view

Comment: i forgot. If i put this code nothing it change but if i replace password with username , all passwords will be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have **logged in**,then you will get the `userId` from **session** right..?So use it here like

```
function edit_member()
{
    $new_member_update_data = array(
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password3'))
            );
    $this->db->where('iUserId',$this->session->userdata('iUserId'));
    $update = $this->db->update('memberships',$new_member_update_data);
    return $update; 
}
```

Consider that `iUserId` will be the field that is **unique** or even a **auto increment** field.

Comment: When i'm logged in i start a session. In the session i have the username that is unique. But when i try to call it in the edit_member function it gives me [Call to undefined method CI_Session::read()]

Comment: Sorry it will be `userdata` not `read`.and also replace userId with the `username` bec as you said it is unique

Answer (score 0):

Check column **password** value and **$this->input->post('password')** value

```
 function edit_member()
 {
      $password = md5($this->input->post('password3');
      $this->db->set('password',$password );
      $this->db->where('password',$this->input->post('password'));
      $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'));
      $update = $this->db->update('memberships');
      return $update; 
 }
```

Comment: If any other user has the same password, then its also replace the others password as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Password value which is in DB, if that is encrypted by MD5 then you have to pass the encrypted value of password in WHERE clause.

```
function edit_member()
{
   $password = md5($this->input->post('password3');
   $this->db->set('password',$password );
   $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password'));
   $update = $this->db->update('memberships');
   return $update; 
}
```